# GCP stops accepting any connection after 00:00 GMT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a HTTP server running on a compute engine instance, but every night at 00:00 GMT, every SSH or HTTP request fails (timeout error). I didn't set any Scheduler for the server to stop at any time, and GCP's console tells me it's still running. The only way to solve this problem is to stop and start the instance everyday...
Can anybody help me please ?

**EDIT :**

[Serial port output logs at the time of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGX4X.png)

Comment: Login before 00:00 and stay logged in. Then you can look around while the problem is happening.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what should I be looking for ?

Comment: If we knew that, your problem would already be solved! You should check the obvious stuff like logs and `dmesg`.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHampton. Sorry if this is obvious but in what logs would I find interesting stuff ? I already checked some but couldn't find anything...

Comment: Wondering if you have a [Preemptible VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible). If so, this might be an expected behavior as per the same document "Compute Engine always stops preemptible instances after they run for 24 hours."

Answer (score 0):

As there is not enough information I would suggest to inspect on [Serial Port Output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) to see operating system, BIOS and other system-level entities logs. It will help you in troubleshooting crashes, failed boots, startup issues, or shutdown issues.

Also, you can check with the [Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) all logs collected from the instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those suggestions !

Comment: And in order for me to complete the question, what informations are missing ?

Comment: The root cause of your issue may come from the service, from the Operating System, from the GCP configuration, from a cron job misconfigured...
as we don't have access to that resources we the community can't really debug further more.
Although, if you use the troubleshooting guide that I shared and you identify where it comes from the issue, don't hesitate to share with us more information so we can continue helping you.
Cheers!

Comment: Ok thank you for those informations. I added the logs from the serial port output but couldn't get any useful informations searching for those logs on Google... Maybe you would have an idea of what they mean ?

Comment: Hello, if you want to check serial port logs I recommend you to check it in the serial port console as specified in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output

Although, if you want to check the http logs you can use the filter on Stackdriver. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview